# Qt: QTableView удаление строки из БД

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11

Есть код, который по идее должен удалять одну строку в QTableView и в БД. Код взят из учебника по Qt(*Макс Шлее, Qt 5.10*).
Я вытаскиваю данные из выделения и закидываю их в фильтр, далее делаю выборку и удаляю все, что будет найдено. При этом в БД все происходит корректно - удаляется ровно та строка которая была выделена(текст которой попал в фильтр)
В интерфейсе же почему-то исчезают все строки и возвращаться не хотят.

Как это исправить?

```
void MainWindow::on_submitDestroying_clicked()
{
    QString text;
    text = ui->goodDestroy_listView->model()->data(ui->goodDestroy_listView->currentIndex()).toString();
    if (text != "")
    {
        QString filter = "gName = '%1'";
                filter  = filter.arg(text);
        model->setFilter(filter);
        model->select();
        model->removeRows(0, model->rowCount());
        model->submitAll();
        ui->goodDestroy_listView->setModel(model);
        model->select();
        /*отладить метод удаления*/
   }
}
```

Comment: я так думаю, проект в студию, а то так никто даже и не возьмется отвечать

Comment: (может надо сделать какой-нибудь `ui->goodDestroy_listView->update()`?)

Comment: или же вьюшка должна вызывать свой `dataChanged`, для этого этот слот должен быть связан с соответствующим сигналом от объекта модели ( c сигналом `QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged`)

Comment: @asianirish попробовано, оно все равно стирает все записи из вьюшки

Comment: может надо каким то образом "отключить" модель от фильтма? А то по логике кода получается, что вьюшка отображает модель с фильтром, а отобранных строк на этот момент уже нет, логично, что не показывает ничего. Например можно попробовать вставить `model->setFilter("TRUE")` после `removeRows(...)`

Comment: @asianirish тоже об этом думал, не нарыл инфы по поводу того как фильтр сбросить лучше всего. К слову я ещё думал что это происходит из-за того, что модель одна используется, но походу это бред уже с моей колокольни

Comment: @JonnyRage очень трудно что-либо сказать по поводу "как фильтр сбросить лучше всего", так как неясно объектом какого класса является `model` (из приведенного вами отрывка это совершенно неясно) - подозреваю, что кастомного. Если это так, то лучшим способом будет определить в этом классе функцию `resetFilter()`, которая и будет сбрасывать фильтр.

Comment: PS  (например путем удаления из целевого запроса раздела `where` или удаления фильтрующего подзапроса, зависит от реализации класса, инстанцией которого есть `model`)

Comment: @asianirish `QSqlTableModel` юзаю

Comment: @asianirish трюк с `model->setFilter("TRUE")` сработал. Оформите ответ, репы насыплю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По логике кода получается, что вьюшка отображает модель с фильтром, а отобранных строк на этот момент уже нет, логично, что не показывает ничего. Например, можно попробовать так:

```
model->removeRows(0, model->rowCount());
model->setFilter("TRUE"); //устанавливаем новый фильт для отображения всех записей
...
```

PS не уверен, но, возможно, сработает и `model->setFilter(QString());`, в документации по `QSqlTableModel` прямых указаний нет, но выглядит правдоподобно.